# Excel function that identifies consecutive values

Tags: excel

I have some data formatted like this

```
       A               B                C

     Phone           Name              Zip
1    111-222-3333    Steve Harvey      12345
2    111-222-3333    Steve Harvey      12354
3    222-333-4444    Barry Badgernaff  65423
4    222-333-4444    Barry Badgernaff  65432
5    333-444-5555    Jim Bob           36521
6    444-555-6666    Mickey Mouse      36541
7    666-777-8888    Donald Duck       39847
8    666-777-8888    Donald Duck       39874
```

What I'm looking to do is identify consecutive duplicate names. If there are duplicates, I want them ignored so I can filter them out

For example

```
       A               B                C        D

     Phone           Name              Zip     Result
1    111-222-3333    Steve Harvey      12345   Duplicate
2    111-222-3333    Steve Harvey      12354   Duplicate
3    222-333-4444    Barry Badgernaff  65423   Duplicate
4    222-333-4444    Barry Badgernaff  65432   Duplicate
5    333-444-5555    Jim Bob           36521   Not A Duplicate
6    444-555-6666    Mickey Mouse      36541   Not A Duplicate
7    666-777-8888    Donald Duck       39847   Duplicate
8    666-777-8888    Donald Duck       39874   Duplicate
```

What I've done is tried identifying these using `=IF(B2=B1, "True", "False)` but it slightly only does what I'm looking for and I end up getting false positives

What else can I try? I don't want to remove the data, just have a cell say if there are consecutive names in the data.

Comment: You can use CountIF function

Comment: Your formula only checks the next row, but you should check the previous one as well. Try this in B2 : `=IF(OR(B2=B1, B2=B3), "True", "False")

Comment: If there are duplicates, do you want to filter so as to show NONE of the rows, or ONE of the rows?

Comment: Can you let us know why they are duplicates when the ZIP is different. Is the ZIP irrelevant? Anyhow, it seems `COUNTIFS()` does what you want

Comment: @EganWolf that worked well. If you add it as an answer below I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula only checks the next row, but you should check the previous one as well.

Try this in B2 : `=IF(OR(B2=B1, B2=B3), "True", "False")`